# Announcing a “Graduation” election for 2021

Tags: discussion, election

**Summary**: Homebrewing Stack Exchange will begin the nomination stage for [an election](https://homebrew.stackexchange.com/election/2) on **October 11th**, as your “graduation” election as a result of having lost your beta label a while back.

The timeline:

- [I have posted](https://homebrew.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/495/2021-moderator-election-qa-question-collection) a question collection post on Meta, so that the community can post questions they'd like to see the candidates answer.
- Starting on October 11th, users can [nominate themselves](https://homebrew.stackexchange.com/election/2). The top questions collected on the previous week will be compiled into a questionnaire on the election page, so that potential moderators can answer them.
- The existing moderator team will need to run in the election if they wish to keep their positions.
- On October 18th, if there are 4 or more candidates, we'll run an election. If not, I'll extend the nomination period for a week. If, at the end of that extension period there are still less than 4 candidates, I'll simply appoint the candidates who've nominated (and aren't already pro-tem mods) and we'll default to considering this a "pro-tem election" just to try to bring the total number of moderators on the site up to 3 (for full details of the process, see [the announcement on Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/314459/experimenting-with-pro-tempore-elections)). (There's a small chance we'll need to [remove a nomination](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/274114/lets-disallow-nominations-from-people-whove-been-suspended-in-the-past-year), but I doubt that will come up.)
- If there is an election, I'll announce the results on meta on October 26th (or November 2nd, if we need to extend the nomination period).

If you have any questions about the process, please stick them in an answer here.